# Help with 100% height and new toolbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a flash object which im currently displaying with 100% width & height (Fullscreen)

However I'm adding a HTML toolbar across the top of the page which is outside of the Flash source.

The toolbar is 60px in height, how can I display the toolbar and the flash object filling the remainder of the screen space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in CSS3:

```
div#flash {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

[More info here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).